# Fetch record from existing table and insert new record in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables xyz and abc. abc is child of xyz, there are two columns in xyz ie, xyz1, xyz2.

Also there are three columns in table abc, ie, xyz1, abc1, abc2.

I want to write a stored procedure to which I will pass two params.

```
123, 456.
```

123 is the primary key of the record present in table xyz.

The query should fetch record of 123 from parent and child table and insert a new record having primary key 456 and rest of field is of record 123.

I am using Oracle 8i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is two insert select statements:

```
create or replace procedure(vi_fromkey integer, vi_tokey integer) as
begin
  insert into xyz (xyz1, xyz2) select vi_tokey, xyz2 from xyz where xyz = vi_fromkey;
  insert into abc (xyz1, abc1, abc2) select vi_tokey, abc1, abc2 from abc where xyz = vi_fromkey;
end;
```